# Linking Firebase App Distrubtion with Google Play - App is not on a published track in Google Play

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-console, firebase-app-distribution

I am trying to link my Google Play Android's App with Firebase App Distribution in order to upload an AAB file to Firebase.

I am pretty sure I've done everything right, but Firebase keeps telling me:

> 1 linked app is not on a published track in Google Play.

I did follow the requirements at ["Before you begin"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-console?hl=en&apptype=aab#before-you-begin)

1. The app do have the same package name in Google Play Console and Firebase App Distribution
2. The app is on Google Play Track for Internal Testing and Closed testing

What am I missing?

[image]
[image]

I tried to submit my app in internal testing track and then I tried to submit my app into closed testing.

I keep receiving the message:

> 1 linked app is not on a published track in Google Play.

Comment: how did you resole this ?